# Is there a collection of basic open source web templates I can use and customize for my projects?

Tags: website-design, open-source

**What are some flexible, open-source, free/public-domain templates I can use that are easy to customize with my text, a logo and a color scheme?** Plain-old HTML5, CSS3, and JavaScript (no Coffescript, Node.js, jQuery, or anything requiring some specific back-end like ASP.NET). It doesn't have to be for mobile either, although the ability to detect-and-self-adjust to mobiles would be a nice-to-have.

Something I could learn some best practices from too would be ideal. Well written code, clean, simple, modern, compatible, and that uses free resources (web fonts, public domain graphics, etc.) that can be given back as a template.

Comment: I purged the comments after editing the question, because they had turned into a discussion and at the end both sides of the story had been clarified. Please feel free to continue it in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/)! Also edited, mainly for readability - it was very long!

Answer (score 2):

Get on the Envato newsletter, they have freebies every month including at least one web design from theme forest.

I'd suggest you take a look into a CSS framework instead of trying to hack a template. Something like [Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/), [Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/) or [YAML](http://www.yaml.de/) for example (there are a whole bunch to choose from). They are not finished web designs, but rather a bunch of pre-built elements you can easily stack together to create your own site.

Answer (score 1):

I've not been very successful in finding *nice* FREE website templates, but I did buy a subscription to this website: http://www.cssigniter.com

They have some really nice WordPress templates for all sorts of things including portfolios...and are quite affordable!

You might also try out fiver.com, [this guy](http://fiverr.com/creativehardik/design-website-template) might be a possibility.

Comment: Thanks for answering! :) Well, the question did mention free as a requirement..

Comment: Yes, I know you said that you wanted it to be free! I just recently went through the same thing that you are trying to sort out, and I decided that $40 was hardly more than free when compared to the time I'd have to spend designing and then coding, much less doing security updates and bug fixes! :-) I probably shouldn't have posted it as an answer, except that in my mind $40 was as good as free...all-things-considered.

Comment: Fair point, if one considers USD 40 to be "near free". :)

Comment: @Robottinosino: When an original theme usually takes $1000+ to design and implement, yes, $40 is near free. Also, if you're actively paranoid about having your designs copied and used for free, why would you expect others to give theirs away to you for free?

Answer (score -1):

Another great option when you're looking for an affordable theme is: http://themeforest.net/

Tons of themes for a multitude of different applications and frameworks.  Check it out when you get a chance!